# How to save contents of Array in CoreData in iOS 6

Tags: core-data, ios6, nsarray

I am fetching the contents of AddressBook  which in turn are copied into an array.Now i want to save this array into CoreData.I know how to insert single values in CoreData.How do i loop through an array to do the same?

Here is what i tried.

```
 -(void)fetchAddressBook
 {
    ABAddressBookRef UsersAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

   //contains details for all the contacts
   CFArrayRef ContactInfoArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(UsersAddressBook);

   //get the total number of count of the users contact
   CFIndex numberofPeople = CFArrayGetCount(ContactInfoArray);

   //iterate through each record and add the value in the array
    for (int i =0; i<numberofPeople; i++) {
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ContactInfoArray, i);
    ABMultiValueRef names = (__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst));
       NSLog(@"name from address book = %@",names); // works fine
       NSString *contactName = (__bridge NSString *)(names);
      [self.reterivedNamesMutableArray addObject:contactName];
       NSLog(@"array content = %@", [self.reterivedNamesMutableArray lastObject]); //This shows null.


}
}

-(void)saveToDatabase
{
  AddressBookAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
  NSManagedObject *newContact;

  for (NSString *object in self.reterivedNamesMutableArray) // this array holds the name of contacts which i want to insert into CoreData. 
  { 
     newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressBook"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [newContact setValue:@"GroupOne" forKey:@"groups"];
     [newContact setValue:object forKey:@"firstName"];
      NSLog(@"Saved the contents of Array"); // this doesn't log.
  }
  [context save:nil];
  }
```

Comment: Did you see the data? When you call save method. all data should be saved. And Is the item in reterivedNamesMutableArray NSString?

Comment: Why are you assigning an NSArray to firstName? Shouldn't it be an NSString?

Comment: Oops !  Well i changed that.But the result is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Note for future readers: This answer refers to the first version of the question.
In order to solve the problem, the code in the question has been updated several times.)</sub>

Your code creates only a single object `newContact`, and the loop modifies
the same object again and again.
If you want multiple objects (one for each address),
you have to create each object separately:

```
for (NSString *object in self.reterivedNamesMutableArray) 
{
    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddressBook"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newContact setValue:@"GroupOne" forKey:@"groups"];
    [newContact setValue:object forKey:@"firstName"];
}
[context save:nil];
```

Comment: I tried it ...but now both groups and first name are showing NULL.

Comment: @Sushrut: Do you print groups/firstName *inside* the loop?

Comment: Well the NSLog inside the loop doesn't log if u r saying about that.

Comment: @Sushrut: Please update your question with the new code and the NSLog statements, so that I can see what is printed and when.

Comment: @Sushrut: 1) Where does the "name from address book" output come from? I cannot see that in your code - 2) If "Saved the contents of Array" is not logged then the array must be empty and the loop is not executed at all. - 3) Logging newContact *after* the loop does not make any sense. To get all saved objects, you have to execute a NSFetchRequest.

Comment: I updated the code to answer your first question and i understand the requirement of NSFetchRequest too although i don't seem to understand why is the loop not getting executed.

Comment: @Sushrut: Did you check if self.reterivedNamesMutableArray is nil or an empty array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36607/discussion-between-sushrut-and-martin-r)

Comment: @MartinR please look at my question by Array and Core Data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189030/how-to-save-data-from-array-in-core-data