# How to save several objects into relationship entity. Xcode

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I have data in array. I loaded them into UITableViewController, and when I select a cell, data from cell adds to Array. Then I want to save data from Array in Core Data, but I cannot make it. I can to save only one file. How can I make it?

```
@IBAction func saveAllData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    if boolForName == true {
        playlistEntity.setValue(currentSong, forKey: "namePlaylist")
        boolForName = false
    }

    for item in arraySong {
        println(item)
        songEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "dataSong")
    }
    playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
    managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    println("play list \(playlistEntity)")
    println("song entity \(songEntity)")
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    var navi = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navi") as! UINavigationController
    presentViewController(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Updated
I remake this code, but it saves the same.

```
@IBAction func saveAllData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    println(index)
    println(currentArray[row])
    var currentFile = currentArray[row]

    var playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    if boolForName == true {
        playlistEntity.setValue(currentSong, forKey: "namePlaylist")
        boolForName = false
    }

    for item in arraySong {
        songEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "dataSong")
        playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        println(songEntity)
    }
    managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    println("play list \(playlistEntity)")
    println("song entity \(songEntity)")
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    var navi = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navi") as! UINavigationController
    presentViewController(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
var arraySong = [String]()
// MARK: IBAction func
@IBAction func saveAllData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var currentFile = currentArray[row]

    var playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    if boolForName == true {
        playlistEntity.setValue(currentSong, forKey: "namePlaylist")
        boolForName = false
    }

    for item in arraySong {
        songEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "dataSong")
        playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)
        println("play list \(playlistEntity)")
        println("song entity \(songEntity)")
    }
    managedObjectContext.save(nil)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    var navi = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navi") as! UINavigationController
    presentViewController(navi, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I tried it but the same I save only the last object from the array.

```
  for var x = 0; x < arraySong.count; x++ {
            var item = arraySong[x]
                println(item)
                songEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "dataSong")
                playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
                managedObjectContext.save(nil)
                //            println("play list \(playlistEntity)")
                //            println("song entity \(songEntity)")
            println(songEntity)
        }
```

So I am adding songs from UITableViewController into the array.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var song = currentArray[row]
    arraySong.append(song)
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried it

```
for var x = 0; x < arraySong.count; x++ {
        var item = arraySong[x]
            println(item)
            var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
            songEntity.setValue(item, forKey: "dataSong")
            playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
            managedObjectContext.save(nil)
            //            println("play list \(playlistEntity)")
            //            println("song entity \(songEntity)")
        println(songEntity)
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**
Still I tried this method but I save only first object which I selected. Are there any methods for it? How can I save several songs( objects) for specific playlist (another entity)?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
        var song = currentArray[row]
//        arraySong.append(song)
        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        var playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
        var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

        if boolForName == true {
            playlistEntity.setValue(currentSong, forKey: "namePlaylist")
            boolForName = false
        }

        songEntity.setValue(song, forKey: "dataSong")
        playlistEntity.setValue(NSSet(object: songEntity), forKey: "song")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)

        println(songEntity)
    }
```

Still I tried it.

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var song = currentArray[row]
    arraySong.append(song)
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    let playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    let songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    if boolForName == true {
        playlistEntity.setValue(currentSong, forKey: "namePlaylist")
        boolForName = false
    }

    for var digit = 0; digit < arraySong.count; digit++ {
        var savedSong = arraySong[digit]
        songEntity.setValue(savedSong, forKey: "dataSong")
        playlistEntity.setValue(Set(arrayLiteral: songEntity), forKey: "song")
        managedObjectContext.save(nil)

    }
```

Entites

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Playlist)
class Playlist: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var namePlaylist: String
    @NSManaged var song: NSSet
}

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Song)
class Song: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var dataSong: String
    @NSManaged var playlist: Playlist

}
```

Relationships entities in Core Data
[image]

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 4**
I tried like but this method saves several new playlists. I knew it. Can anyone show me programmatically it?

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    //
    let indexP = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var song = currentArray[row]

    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    let playlistEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Playlist", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject
    let songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! NSManagedObject

    songEntity.setValue(song, forKey: "dataSong")
    playlistEntity.setValue(Set(arrayLiteral: songEntity), forKey: "song")
    println(songEntity)
    println(playlistEntity)
    managedObjectContext.save(nil)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what *"I can to save only one file"* means. Core Data usually has only a single persistent store file. How exactly does your code not work?

Comment: @TomHarrington I can to save into core data only the last object from array.

Comment: You're inserting **one** object for entity `Song` and then you're overwriting the data of that single instance again and again in the repeat loop. You need one object for **each** song

Comment: How can I make it? I want to make that I select object from UITableViewController and I save it into Core Data, I want to make a playlist. I updated the code above. @vadian

Comment: I'm not that familiar with CoreData but at least try to move the line `var songEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Song",…` in the repeat loop to insert multiple objects and delete the `save` line in the repeat loop, it's sufficient to save the data once

Comment: @vadian It doesn't work for me again. I can to save the same only last object.

Comment: @vadian please look at my update 2.

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not so familiar with CoreData, from the workflow it looks correct (except to save the context in each iteration) but I have no idea about the relationship between the entities.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you select a row you are creating one new playlist and one new song.  Create your playlist before selecting songs and only update the relationship when you add a new song.

Comment: I assume your songs and playlists are connected.  I don't know the details of your data model.

Comment: I made a screenshot, please look up on it. I think that I must add song into the specific playlist but I don't know how make it.

Comment: If you create your songEntity using `as! Song` you should be able to just use `songEntity.playlist = playlistEntity`.

Comment: No, I don't. I create as! NSManagedObject

Comment: Do you have a need to only refer to it as its parent?

Comment: How can I add songs into specific exist playlist?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helps me.